# How to find what is dependent on a particular library?

Tags: installation, libraries

I have a library installed that I'm reluctant to remove because I don't know what is dependent on it.

How can I find that out?

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to just rename it and see what happens. If everything works, fine, if not, just name it back to its original name.

Answer (score 1):

There may be more elegant solutions to this question but you could use `grep` or similar to search all the files on the website for references to the library. If you don't have direct access to a command line, you may be able to run `grep` from a script as per https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/29914/31686. Alternatively, you could download the website files to your local machine and use whatever tools you have on your local machine to search the file structure.

You could also search the database e.g. using `phpMyAdmin` for references to the library.

Comment: Yes, ``grep`` is indeed a nice solution. Alternatively you could use the search functionality in an IDE (PHPStorm, Visual Studio, Netbeans, Eclipse, etc) to find the files where the library is used.

Comment: Well, I don't agree that `grep` is a "nice" solution. Perhaps the only one available? I'm not comfortable with these make-shift solutions, I feel there should be an "official" way, but maybe there isn't.